# SQLAlchemy creating query with filter_by dynamically

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am new to python and SQLAlchemy, so excuse me if this question sounds obvious:
I am trying to create a dynamic query by passing the column names to filter on as :

```
filter_by={"or":{"origin_source_id":"MX01",
                   "origin_client_id":"JP0001"}}
```

**I can have 'or' / 'and'/ '>'/'<'  as operators**

the objective is to create an expression like:

```
session.query(dbClass).filter(dbClass.origin_client_id=='JP0001' or dbClass.origin_source_id=='MX01')
```

and if the following is defined :

```
filter_by={"origin_source_id":"MX01"}
```

to create an expression like:

```
session.query(dbClass).filter(dbClass.origin_source_id=="MX01")
```

and if it is defined as:

```
filter_by={"and":{"origin_source_id":"MX01",
                           "origin_client_id":"JP0001"}}
```

the expression should be:

```
session.query(dbClass).filter(dbClass.origin_client_id=='JP0001' or dbClass.origin_source_id=='MX01')
```

Can anyone explains to me how to parse filter_by and extract the values to build the query expression ?

I am not succeeding in knowing where to start.

Thank you

Comment: Try [`or_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html). Otherwise, elasticsearch has fully support for these kind of things.

Comment: not sure i understand the "try or". I am not keen to use an external package to do that. I really appreciate knowing at least how to parse the filter_by expression and get its elements